# Asp.NET MVC 4 load the pdf in modal window

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, modal-dialog

I've a table with rows inside my view  and one of the column as view pdf , I would like to load the pdf in side the modal window. I've control get filecontentresult from DB as well.

Answer (score 0):

Abstract from the similar Stackoverflow thread - [Display Adobe pdf inside a div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2740297/display-adobe-pdf-inside-a-div)

```
 <div> <object data="test.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="300" height="200"> alt : <a href="test.pdf">test.pdf</a> </object> </div>
```