# How to change pdf tab title in browser

Tags: php, codeigniter, pdf

My pdf file is open in browser tab. In the title of pdf tab instead of name it shows the url how can i changed it .I am using codeigniter framework and using Mpdf library for pdf.

Comment: Please add your PDF name and url in your question,and what change you required

Comment: My repitiions is low thats why i cant upload image.

Comment: Did not getting the issue, please provide more detail,your question is about pdf that not opening in browser.

Comment: @WaqasKhan clarify your question.

Comment: @RahamSher now check plz if u have any idea kindly share.

Comment: found a solution at this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/61047800/5723524

Answer (score 11):

Your PDF document should have Title metadata set. Afterwards, browser will use it for rendering tab title.

http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/PDF18.html

Comment: But i open the pdf in browser. I am not downloading it. @Tigran Tokmajyan

Comment: So you have PDF and you want to serve it through browser, right? To achieve title appearing in tab, you should edit the PDF and set the `title` metadata.

Comment: found a solution at this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/61047800/5723524

Answer (score 2):

In Acrobat Pro, open the PDF and select File -> Properties -> Description and then edit the meta data title (and others if required) as you see fit.

We only saw the title being displayed like this in Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

Put it in a div inside a page and change the page title like this:

```
<head>
  <title>YOUR TAB TITLE</title>
</head>
```

and then:

```
<div>
<object data="test.pdf" type="application/pdf" 
width="300" height="200">
    alt : <a href="test.pdf">test.pdf</a>
   </object>
</div>
```

You can also set the object width and height to match the page.

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2740297/display-adobe-pdf-inside-a-div)

Answer (score 0):

For changing PDF tab title in browser, you need to update "title" in property.

If you have PDF editor you can do it easily. Else it is not editable.

You can use any of the tool online to edit the title.
I did it using below link.

https://www.sejda.com/edit-pdf-metadata

Answer (score -1):

Try this. It's so simple.

```
$mpdf->SetTitle('My Title');
```