# Laravel 5 set file name and title page when view pdf file in browser

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, amazon-s3, storage

I need view a pdf file in browser - which store in my Storage. But I can not set the page title by file name, it display a name what I don't know where it from. My file name is ***TestPDFFile_1.pdf***

Can someone help me?

[image]

here is my code

```
$folderName = config('filesystems.folder_test');
$fileName = $file->name;

$file = Storage::disk('s3')->get($folderName . "/" . $fileName);

$response = Response::make($file, 200);
$response->header('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');
$response->header('Content-Disposition', 'inline; filename="'.$fileName.'"');

return $response;
```

Comment: Where you set file name to your PDF?

Comment: $fileName = $file->name; // here your filename is coming (TestPDFFile_1 )?

Comment: Try this once. It may help you.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27652937/how-to-change-pdf-tab-title-in-browser/27653004#27653004

Comment: tks you guys so much, let me try it :D