# Laravel - Set page title when using Response::make to view pdf file

Tags: laravel, pdf

I am trying to set the page title in Laravel to be the name of the file that is being viewed in the browser. I have looked through the documentation and questions on stack overflow and cannot seem to find the solution. The page title keeps defaulting to the primary key

```
public function download(SomeModel $document)
{
   if(Storage::disk('s3')->exists($document->file_path)) {
       return \Response::make(Storage::disk('s3')->get($document->file_path), 200, [
           'Content-Type' => 'application/pdf',
           'Content-Disposition' => 'inline; filename="'. $document->custom_file_name .'"'
            ]);
    }
    return view('errors.404');
}
```

How can I make it to where the `<title></title>` of the page is using the `$document->custom_file_name` as opposed to being the id.

Comment: found a simple solution, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/61047800/5723524

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the Title metadata on your pdf document, then the browser will interpret it as the title automatically.

http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/PDF18.html

Comment: Is there anyway to set this when the file is uploaded to S3, that way the user doesn't have to do this manually?

Comment: Personally don't have much experience with S3 but have a look at this, might work: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/add-object-metadata.html . However I'm not sure how you could set this on upload

Comment: Actually, on upload I think you can directly post with a metadata param, i.e :   `Metadata: { title: 'foobar' }`