# Open pdf in a <div> on click of menu

Tags: javascript, html, css, pdf, twitter-bootstrap-3

In my project i had a side menu(left). `OnClick` of each **Button** in  menu a pdf should be loaded in middle of my page(i.e., in a `div`).I am able to load a pdf in middle of my page(`div`),but not on click of my menu **Buttons**. `iframes` should not be used in my project.please help me out

Here is my code(sample code) on click of menu items the pdf should load in div class="col-sm-9 col-md-10"

```
<div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar">

 <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
                <li style="padding-left:1em;"><h4>MENU</h4></li>
                <li class="active"><a href="shows.aspx" class="user-icon">TV Shows</a></li>
                <li><a href="history.aspx" class="sub-icon">History</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="menu1">Movies</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="menu">Sports</a></li>
                <li><a href="shows.aspx" class="user-icon">TV Shows</a></li>
```

```
<div class="col-sm-9 col-md-10">
```

Comment: Can you include the code that you already made?

Comment: sure u can see it above.i included  <embed src="sample.pdf" width="100%" height="610px" alt="pdf" pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/products/acrobat/readstep2.html">  in my div class using this i am able to load pdf in a div.but i want to load a PDF on click of my menu Buttons.Guide me

Answer (score 1):

Your div should have object tag embedded i.e

```
<div class="col-sm-9 col-md-10">
   <object data="#" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="750">
        alt : pdf not loaded yet
   </object>
</div>
```

Then after the onclicked of the menu, you then change the data="" in the object tag to your specific pdf source i.e

```
$(".menu, .menu1").on("click", function(){
    $("object").attr('data', 'your-pdf.pdf');
 });
```

you can decide the logic at which you want to show your pdf base on the menu the above script would get you started.

Answer (score 0):

You can most likely use the [`<object>` tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/object). You may have to have one tagged and reconstruct it on a click using javascript.

I can't really provide more specifics without knowing how you're project is layed out.

Here's a more fleshed out [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2740297/display-adobe-pdf-inside-a-div)

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a[href$='.pdf']").each(function(){
        $(this).attr('href', 'http://docs.google.com/viewer?embedded=true&url=' + $(this).attr('href'));
    });

    $("a[href$='.doc']").each(function(){
        $(this).attr('href', 'http://docs.google.com/viewer?embedded=true&url=' + $(this).attr('href'));
    });

});

$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    openEffect  : 'none',
    closeEffect : 'none',
    iframe : {
        preload: false
    }
});
```

```html
<a class="fancybox" data-fancybox-type="iframe" href="http://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/fw4.pdf">Test PDF</a>

<a class="fancybox" data-fancybox-type="iframe" href="www.snee.com/xml/xslt/sample.doc">Test Doc</a>
```