# Can I use JavaScript to scroll inside an embedded PDF viewer in the browser?

Tags: javascript, html, pdf-viewer, object-tag

I am using the following code ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3174589/10139616)) to display a PDF in a `div` on my page.

```
<div>
    <object data="data:application/pdf;base64,JVBERi0xLjcKCjEgMCBvYmogIC..." type="application/pdf" width="300" height="200">
        alt : <a href="test.pdf">test.pdf</a>
    </object>
</div>
```

[image: PDF-view]

Is there any way I can scroll the PDF from outside the `<object>` ? I want to use separate Javascript to scroll through pages on the PDF.

Comment: I understand Chrome's PDF viewer is implemented using the Shadow DOM - and I don't believe JavaScript can cross the Shadow DOM boundary easily.